# How to handle special characters In CSV file

Tags: android

i am creating csv file in my app problem i am facing is that while writing normal code for creating csv file i am able to manage new line character but can't handle (,) in content and if i am using opencsv library than it will handle (,) but if there is new line character in string then it leaves all the content next to \n. please suggest how to handle it .

```
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
         {
                  String _address=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                  if(_address!=null)
                   writer.append(_address);
                  else
                     writer.append("Unknown");

                   writer.append(',');

                  String _body=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                  if(_body.contains("\n"))
                      _body=_body.replace("\n", "\\n");
                 if(_body!=null)
                   writer.append('"'+_body+'"');
                 else
                    writer.append("");
                    writer.append(',');

                    String _IsRead=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read"));
                    writer.append(_IsRead);
                    writer.append(',');
                    String SmsDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                    writer.append(SmsDate);
                    writer.append(',');
                  // writer.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")));
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) 
                    writer.append("Inbox");
                    else 
                    writer.append("Sent");                      
                    writer.append('\n');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do what Excel does:

1. If there is double-quote then add another one.
2. Each item put in double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the data before writing it as a CSV file.
The character ',' could be replaced with a character like '~' or any other for that matter, the probability of which occurring in the data is very less. This is not a fool proof solution, but gets the work done.

Comment: Maybe you could write the data as '\n' separated text file, just like any other file, then there would not be any problem.